# Drupal Entity Registration module - List of deleted registrations

Tags: drupal, registration

I have events (sport trainings), created manually. Users can register for that events with Entity Registration module.

What I need is a list of deleted registrations. I can create a rule "after deleting a registration create a new entity" with a date field (when registration was deleted) and a field contains user. But problem is... I don't know, how to store name of that related event.

Is there a way to store a name or date of related event, when registration was deleted? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I have messed with entity registration, but if I am not mistaken, isn't there a registration state option?

This may be a bit of a workaround, but could you disable the ability for users to delete a registration outright, but allow them to change the state of their registration to a state called "Deleted"? That way you would still have the registration and still have all of the data associated with it.

For a more streamlined method, you could add a button or something that runs an action that changes that user's registration to state "Deleted" but no button to change it back, so they cannot un-delete (assuming you don't want them to be able to un-delete).